# Runtime Error while uploading a photo to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, upload, runtime-error

Why do I see this error while trying to upload a photo to server:
I have these codes:
In Web.config:

```
<configuration> 
    <system.web> 
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" /> 
    </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

And for upload:

```
public static void UploadImage(string folder, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string uploadFolderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + folder);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolderPath, fileName);
        file.SaveAs(filePath);
    }
```

And the error is:
[image]

EDIT:

I had a domain named `taghbazar.ir` and a hosting on it.I bought another domain named `uask.ir` and change my hosting space from `taghbazar.ir` to `uask.ir`.I think the problem is there.How to solve it?
The error says:

[image]

Comment: As the error page mentions, have you tried setting the customErrors mode to OFF and see the detailed error?

Comment: you should probably check with your hosting provider about the exact location where you are allowed to save files.

Comment: Lots of thanks for your help my friend.;)